# Migrating to cloud and multi tenant DB

Tags: java, cloud, pentaho, multi-tenant

We have got a web based Java application which we are planning to migrate to cloud with an intention that multiple clients will be using it in a SaaS based environment. The current architecture of the application is quite asynchronous in nature. There are 4 different modules, each having a database of its own. When there is a need of data exchange between the modules we push the data using Pentaho and make use of a directory structure to store the interim data file, which is then picked up by the other module to populate its database. Given the nature of our application this asynchronous communication is very important for us.

Now we are facing a couple of challenges while migrating this application to cloud:

1. We are planning to use Multi Tenancy on our database server, but how do we ensure that the flat files we use for transferring the data between different modules are also channelized to their respective tenants in the DB.
2. Since we are planning to host this in cloud, would seek your views, if keeping a text file on a cloud server would be safe from a data security perspective.

Answer (score 1):

File storage in cloud is safe and you can use control IAM roles setup to control the permissions of a file. Cloud providers like Google (*Cloud storage*), Amazon (*AWS S3*), etc provides a secure and scalable infrastructure to maintain files in the cloud.

In general setup, cloud storage provides you with buckets which are tagged with a global unique identification. For a multi-tenant setup you can create multiple buckets for individual tenants and store the necessary data feeds in it. Next, you can have jobs batch or streaming jobs using kettle (Pentaho) to push it to the right database based on the unique bucket definition.

Alternatively, you can also push (*like other answers*) to a streaming setup (like ActiveMQ, Kafka, etc) with user specific topics and have a streaming service (*using java or pentaho*) to ingest the data to respective database based on the topic.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot realistically give any specific advice without knowing more
   about your system. However, based on my experience, I would
   recommend switching to message queues, something like Kafka would
   work nicely.
2. Yes, cloud providers offer enough security for static file storage. You can
   limit access however you see fit, for example using AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

1- The multi tenancy may create a bit of issue while transferring the files. But from what information you have given the process of flat file movement across application will not be impacted. Still you can think of moving to MQ mode for passing the data across.

2-From data security view, AWS provides lot of features at access level, MFA, etc. If it needs to be highly secured i would recommend to get AWS Private cloud where nothing is shared with any one at any level.